# Hide "Mark as Complete Check Box" in Sharepoint 2013 Task List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, task-list

I want to hide the  "Mark as Complete Check Box" in Sharepoint 2013 Task List view. Is it possible? What is the best way to do so? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove "Completed" field from current view and it will take away the mark as completed check box.

Edit view,  you should be seeing "Completed" field selected,  just uncheck that and save the view.

[image]

Hope this helps,  mark this as answer if it did...